# is linux based system needed for python hacking?

Tags: python, linux

is a Linux based system needed for python hacking? I just watching my Udemy ***ethical hacking with python*** course and

### **he kept saying you need Linux based O.P system.**

Why you need a Linux Operating System
I didn't understand it because he didn't explain why we need to use it so I'm asking here can you explain?

Comment: The course work is likely _taught_ on a “Linux” system, using tools and commands that are available in such an environment. Like a text books, classes generally assumes everyone has the same reading material.. and no: it’s not _technically_ required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you don't need a GNU/Linux system to learn Python, but since you are learning it with an online course the course's materials may be written for a certain GNU/Linux distribution. So, it would be easier for you to follow the course if you have the software suggested for the course.

In the course you mentioned, they use Kali Linux, a distribution for security and forensic professionals. I suppose, it has a lot of tools for hacking preinstalled and working out of the box. In the introduction, the course also describes how to install the distribution in a virtual  machine, so you can use it on a Mac or Windows.